# Approximation algorithem for finding diameter of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Given Graph **G=(*V,E*)** ,undirected and weightless, we would want to find the value of diameter *D* of graph **G**. Show how to find a value X such that X<=D<=2*X in running time of O(|V|+|E|).

Now, to find the actual diameter of graph you simply need to run BFS twice.Once from and arbitrary node and then from the most distend node. But in this question I need to find an approximation to the diameter. My guess was to run BFS once and choosing the largest distance as the diameter. There are two edge cases that can occur.

The first one occur when the chosen node is located on the perimeter of graph **G**. The distend node will be located on the opposite side of the perimeter and thus *X* will be equal to *D*.

The second case will occur when the chosen node is in the center of **G** and *X* will be equal to half of *D*( *X* in this case will be the radios of G).

This was my answer to this question. And yet I was given 15/25 . Is there an edge case that I didn't handle or was it wrong from the start?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Now, to find the actual diameter of graph you simply need to run BFS twice.Once from and arbitrary node and then from the most distend node`. That works for a tree. Assuming *diameter* of an arbitrary graph is its longest path - this problem is known as the longest path problem and is NP-Complete, this is why you only want an approximation.

Comment: I didn't know that, Thank you. But it still doesn't help me figure out what was wrong with my answer.

Comment: The diameter is the longest shortest path between two vertices, not the longest path; it is solvable in polynomial time and probably not NP-complete.

Comment: I think you got 15/25 because you did not provide a formal proof, you only showed it is correct for two cases without proving the algorithm works for all other cases as well.

Comment: Every other case will definitely be between the center of the graph and its perimeter

Comment: I have no idea where you study, but in the Technion in Haifa, Israel - the main focus of the algorithms course (in CS faculty) is formally proving correctness - and not only finding the algorithm (and a lot of the time in the course is spent on proves). Maybe it also applies to your facility. So, if you did not provide a formal proof - you failed to complete the ex. according to this logic. But this is really dependent on the main focus of the specific course you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

60% seems a bit harsh to this former algorithms TA -- you gave the correct algorithm and identified the extremal cases for the two inequalities. Nevertheless, I agree with amit that you needed to give a formal proof. If your graders are particularly strict, you might have needed to say a word or two as well about why your algorithm is linear-time.

Here's the start of a formal proof. Let d(v, w) be the minimum length of a path between vertices v and w. The diameter is defined to be D = max_{v, w} d(v, w). Your algorithm chooses an arbitrary vertex s and outputs X = max_{w} d(s, w).

You need to do a little bit of algebra to show two facts: that X <= D and that D <= 2 X. You'll need the triangle inequality d(a, b) + d(b, c) >= d(a, c), which holds for all vertices a, b, c, as well as the symmetry d(a, b) = d(b, a).